# heroku + revision control

Tags: git, svn, version-control, heroku

I've run into an interesting problem here in using heroku + git + SVN.

Basically, the setup right now for my site is as follows:
Our team --> SVN repo (free one from Assembla) ---> Heroku

As in, our team has changes which we commit to our SVN repo. When we feel confident in what we have, we push the latest in our repo to Heroku.

There are a bunch of issues here. Namely, as of right now, I'm only able to push to Heroku from the machine where I first setup our Heroku app. The SVN repo has all our Heroku/GIT files in there ... but I've tried checking it out separately (on the same machine from where we push) and then pushing from there, but I get a git error that the HEAD is bad (fatal: bad object HEAD). Not sure what that means or how to fix it.

The main reason I want to do all this is because I want to make sure that we can have some sort of setup where we have full working versions of our app to fall back to if things go awry. For example, I wanted to have a pushes directory where we could copy stuff from trunk in SVN to a pushes/ directory and then push to heroku from there. That way, if the latest version was messed up, we could quickly push from pushes/. Of course, as I mentioned, this is not an option right now because I can only push from 1 specific directory on one specific machine.

Any ideas on what is the best way to manage this setup? Is my idea for having full working versions unnecessary? I don't mind redoing stuff entirely, or switching from SVN to git even (thought I would prefer not to, I wouldn't mind if that would simplify things), etc. How do others collaborate & do revision control with Heroku?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know heroku ignores pushes on branches other than master but does it still store them?

If so, you could do your work on a development branch and merge that to master when you want to deploy that would be an option.

Alternatively why not just use an assembla or github git repository or [unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/) for a free repo?

Comment: well so if I went with assembla git, would it simplify my life you think? I just don't get why that would fix things for me I guess... Will there be an easy way of having this additional folder for pushing to heroku or what?

I guess I'm not understanding your first sentence very well -- so if I have this app, I will now set it up to use git. OK, cool. Now, I have a git repo in assembla & a heroku app to push. What next??

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Heroku builds when you push to it.  You could push to heroku less frequently than you push to assembla.